# AMP HTML animation is not behaving correctly on iPad

Tags: ios, css, ipad, animation, amp-html

AMP animation is not behaving correctly on iPad.
I want to move the section on the scroll, which is working correctly for all devices including iPad pro and iPhone but not on iPad.

Comment: Without more detail it's impossible to answer this question. This sounds like a bug though and maybe it's best to file a bug report (with a reproducible sample) here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new.